# Wordpress site within a wordpress site, .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I was asked to move one working WP site (site 2) onto a folder of another WP site (site 1)(because the first site is being blocked in China and the second isn't).

so the complete URL ended up being www.site1.com/site2

I managed to do so but the links on the second site are no longer working, they show a 404 from site 1 but the URL seems OK

www.site1.com/site2/path_to_page_on_site_2 -> 404

I assume it is because of the .htaccess from site 1:

```
# Redirect images
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^font/(.*)$ /wp-content/themes/site1/font/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^timages/(.*)$ /wp-content/themes/site1/image/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^videos/(.*)$ /wp-content/themes/site1/video/$1 [L]
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Site 2 has a "standard" .htaccess from WP

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

if it is an htaccess problem, how can i stop the htaccess from site 1 affecting site 2?
if it is something else, how can i fix it?

thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't your site2's `.htaccess` file have a `RewriteBase /site2/` ?

Comment: I just changed the RewriteBase to /site2/ but I still have the same problem

Comment: Please try by modifying `RewriteRule` to `RewriteRule . /site2/index.php [L]` . I just did a test installation on my local machine and with a test site installed in `/Test/`, and under a different installation under `/` it was working properly. Can you access the admin area of `site2`? Have you also updated the database of `site2` to reflect the new path?

Comment: Thanks for that Nikola!, pages are loading now, but the images are missing, they point to site1, any idea how to fix those?
yes, i can access the admin are on site2 and the database points to the new path

Comment: Can you give an example of how the images point to site1? How did you migrate your db? Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514867/moving-database-one-domain-to-other/13515800#13515800) answer - I have added a detailed description on how to fully migrate a WordPress database.

Comment: The images have relative paths (e.g. wp-content/uploads/2012/11/look-inside.jpg but it ends up pointing to www.site1.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/whr-cover-look-inside.jpg). Ideally any call under site2/ should be redirected to site2. (BTW i up voted the wrong comment).
I copied the database to the new site and change the URL to point to site2

Comment: But aren't they relative with a slash at the beginning? Because if they are not, then if you go to a page let's say `www.site1.com/site2/example/another`, the images would point to `www.site1.com/site2/example/another/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/whr-cover-look-inside.jpg`. The behavior that you see should be observed if the images have a slash at the beginning, like so: `/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/whr-cover-look-inside.jpg` - this makes them relative to the root directory. I would just make all the images URL's absolute.

Comment: Yup, i ended up changing them to absolute. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to write an answer on how you fixed your issue(basically that your .htaccess wasn't correct and what you had to change) and then marking your answer as accepted. This way your question won't remain in the "Unanswered" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do what i was after thanks to Nikola's comment. This is the final htaccess file for site2

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site2/index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I wanted to redirect all the calls to site2 to the appropriate folder so relative paths were not affected but was not able to do it with htaccess, so i had to do a replace in the database to make them absolute.